# Display power of 10 at axis' end

Tags: gnuplot, axis, axis-labels

My data runs from 0 to 800000 on the x-axis and I have 4 plots in a square. To make the scale readable, I'd like to label the ticks from 0 to 8 (i.e. with `%1.0t`) and write the *10^5 at the end of the scale. I tried several format options, but all of them add *10^5 or e5 behind each tick. Is there a way to only put it in the end instead of each one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set xtics 100000 format "%1.0t"
set label "*10^5" at graph 1, 0  offset 4
```

However the more conventional approach is to explain the scale in the axis label:

```
set xlabel "Whatever it is (x 10^5)"
```

Comment: Somehow the first code sample doesn't work, maybe because I use a multiplot? But I also thought about the second option and if it's the more conventional approach, even better. So I will use this one.

Comment: Probably you just need to make the right margin wider so that your extra label fits on the page. `set rmargin 10`